# MacBook Air M1 Occasionally will not sleep (macOS 12.6.3)

Tags: sleep-wake

Ocassionally my MacBook will refuse to sleep. It does not matter if I shut the lid or if I select Sleep from the Apple menu, it won't sleep and overnight it loses about 10% battery. The only way to resolve this is to restart the Mac, but even then it will randomly stop working, which is both annoying and concerning. I am currently on a trip right now, and has lost about 20% of my battery while only using the computer for about 5 minutes.

- I do not have any devices connected
- Wi-Fi and bluetooth are off
- Low power mode is on
- No devices are connected
- There are no regular applications running, just iStat Menus and Little Snitch, of which I've never had any issues with on older macs.
- Nothing in activity monitor is "preventing sleep"

Running `pmset -g`:

```
System-wide power settings:
 SleepDisabled      0
Currently in use:
 standby              1
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 SleepServices        0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                10 (sleep prevented by powerd)
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 tcpkeepalive         0
 lowpowermode         1
```

Running `pmset -g log` yeilds a massive amount of text (it takes a good few seconds to run), consisting of this message, repeated:

```
2023-05-18 05:23:11 -0500 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:86%) 1 secs    
2023-05-18 05:23:12 -0500 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(70 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(101 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(117 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(115 ms)] [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(68 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(116 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(114 ms)] [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(70 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(99 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(117 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(115 ms)] [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(69 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(117 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(116 ms)] [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(70 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(99 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(117 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(115 ms)] [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(70 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(101 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(117 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(115 ms)] [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(67 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(101 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(116 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(114 ms)] [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(71 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(118 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(114 ms)] [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(69 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(101 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(117 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(115 ms)] [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(69 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(101 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(117 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(116 ms)] [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(70 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(117 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(115 ms)] [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(68 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(117 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(115 ms)] [AppleCS42L83Audio driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(71 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(101 ms)]
```

Comment: You should start by turning off iStat Menus and Little Snitch. That will rule them out for sure, (and give you less data to worry about ;-) ). See if it will go to sleep in Safe boot mode. Also: any reason you're not updating to Ventura?